# 2011 Corolla fan running but no air coming out

Tags: toyota, corolla, heater-blower

I have a 2011 Toyota Corolla that the fan seems to be running full blast and air barely comes out of the defrost, front dash and floor vents.  Just a little comes out of defrost and none out of the dash vents.  Any ideas?

Comment: I did notice that the cabin filter looks like it is loose in the casing.  Is there suppose to be something that snaps over it after it is inserted?

Answer (score 0):

One of the vent doors is stuck or a cable or lever broken - have to check.